# Hubstaff - retrieve data with php cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to connect with hubstaff api, has anyone ever tried it? I'm a newbie in php-cURL, how do you convert this to PHP Curl?

```
curl -H "App-Token: BMyQnju-4tknuBQMsN0ujr6NWF5ohQaP9de8AWMJXik" -H "Auth-Token: X-vfv2c7jf_0NKoHLbX1t4yftK-TI-jZ4d7roNegw24" "http://api.hubstaff.com/v1/users"
```

It also would not show any result of I do this:

```
// Standard data
    $data['app_token'] = $this->app_token;

    // Debugging output
    $this->debug = array();
    $this->debug['HTTP Method'] = $http_method;

    // Create a cURL handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'App-Token: ' . $this->app_token,
        'Content-Type: application/xml'
    ));


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    // Send data
    if (!empty($data)) {

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

        // Debugging output
        $this->debug['Posted Data'] = $data;
    }

    // Execute cURL request
    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Save CURL debugging info
    $this->debug['Last Response'] = $curl_response;
    $this->debug['Curl Info'] = curl_getinfo($ch);

    // Close cURL handle
    curl_close($ch);

    // Parse response
    $response =$curl_response;// $this->parseAsciiResponse($curl_response);

    // Return parsed response
    return $response;
```

Im just trying to get my Auth-Token

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you solved this ? I've got similar problem.

Comment: @MichalOlszowski Yup, I solved this, and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Michal I have solved my own problem and created this simple class to help anyone else in connecting with hubstaff fast. feel free for any suggestions and optimizations

```
class HubstaffApi {

private $app_token = '';
private $auth_token = '';
private $debug = [];

public function __construct($app_token, $auth_token) {
    $this->app_token = $app_token;
    $this->auth_token = $auth_token;
}

private function sendRequest($api_method, $http_method = 'GET', $data = null) {
    // Standard data
    $data['app_token'] = $this->app_token;
    $request_url = "https://api.hubstaff.com/v1/";

    // Debugging output
    $this->debug = array();
    $this->debug['Request URL'] = $request_url . $api_method;

    // Create a cURL handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url . $api_method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'App-Token: ' . $this->app_token,
        'Auth-Token: ' . $this->auth_token
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $http_method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    // Send data
    if (!empty($data)) {

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

        // Debugging output
        $this->debug['Posted Data'] = $data;
    }

    // Execute cURL request
    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Save CURL debugging info
    $this->debug['Last Response'] = $curl_response;
    $this->debug['Curl Info'] = curl_getinfo($ch);

    // Close cURL handle
    curl_close($ch);

    // Parse response
    $response = $curl_response;

    // Return parsed response
    return $response;
}

public function users(array $parameters = array()) {
    return $this->sendRequest('users', 'GET', $parameters);
}

public function activities(array $parameters = array()) {
    return $this->sendRequest('activities', 'GET', $parameters);
}

public function screenshots(array $parameters = array()) {
    return $this->sendRequest('screenshots', 'GET', $parameters);
}

}
```

You can simply use this by:

```
$Hubstaff = new HubstaffApi(
        YOUR_APP_TOKEN, 
YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN); //simply get auth token in developer.hubstaff 's generator, it doesn't expire anyway.

$response = $Hubstaff->activities([
    "start_time" => "2015-09-10T00:00:00+08:00:00",
    "stop_time" => "2015-09-10T24:00:00+08:00:00",
    "users" => YOUR_HUBSTAFF_ID
]);

    echo $response;
```